# Ayuda con una consulta de dos tablas

Tags: mysql

Estoy realizando un login y en el mismo, quiero consultar dos tablas y que segun lo que ingrese en el input me traiga un solo resultado de los tablas que consulte, coloco la manera en que la estoy haciendo pero no he tenido éxito

```
SELECT u.id_usuario, u.id_tipousuario,rol, u.correo_usuario, u.contrasena_usuario, 
       tc.id_tienda,tc.id_tipousuario,tc.correo_tienda,tc.contrasena_tienda 
       FROM usuarios AS u, tiendas_cafe AS tc 
       INNER JOIN tipos_usuarios USING(id_tipousuario) 
       WHERE u.correo_usuario= :correo_usuario=tc.correo_tienda= :correo_tienda
```

Probando esta otra manera:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios,tiendas_cafe 
         WHERE correo_usuario=correo_tienda='correo' LIMIT 1
```

me trae el resultado pero me trae toda la fila de la otra tabla

estructura de tablas

INSERT
INTO
    `usuarios`(
        `id_usuario`,
        `id_tipousuario`,
        `id_status`,
        `nombre_usuario`,
        `apellido_usuario`,
        `id_pais`,
        `id_ciudad`,
        `direccion_usuario`,
        `telefono_usuario`,
        `correo_usuario`,
        `genero`,
        `fecha_nacimiento_usuario`,
        `ubicacion_usuario`,
        `ltd_usuario`,
        `lng_usuario`,
        `contrasena_usuario`,
        `img_perfil_usuario`
    )

INSERT
INTO
    `tiendas_cafe`(
        `id_tienda`,
        `id_tipousuario`,
        `id_status`,
        `nombre_tienda`,
        `propietario`,
        `concepto`,
        `descripcion`,
        `id_pais`,
        `id_ciudad`,
        `direccion_tienda`,
        `telefono_tienda`,
        `correo_tienda`,
        `barista`,
        `tipo_cafe`,
        `fecha_aniversario`,
        `ubicacion_tienda`,
        `ltd_tienda`,
        `lng_tienda`,
        `contrasena_tienda`,
        `img_perfil_tienda`,
        `img_portada_tienda`,
        `img_galeria_tienda`,
        `url_video_tienda`
    )

La consulta sería algo como esto:

SELECT correo_usuario,correo_tienda FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN tiendas_cafe tc ON u.id_tipousuario = tc.id_tipousuario WHERE u.correo_usuario=tc.correo_tienda LIKE '%usuario@usuario.com%'LIMIT 1

Comment: ¿Por qué columna se relacionan las tablas?  La segunda consulta no podrá  jamás relacionar las tablas. Y en la primera intervienen tres tablas en vez de dos, además el WHERE es incorrecto. Debería ser escrita más o menos así: `SELECT u.id_usuario, u.id_tipousuario FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN otra-tabla ot ON u.id_usuario=ot.llave_foranea  WHERE u.correo_usuario= :correo_usuario AND ot.correo_tienda= :correo_tienda LIMIT 1;` Para tener una respuesta adecuada muestra la estructura de tus tablas (no una imagen), como se relacionan y el resultado que quieres obtener.

Comment: @A.Cedano Las tablas no estan relacionadas, yo solo quiero consultar las dos tablas en la misma query para saber en que tabla esta el correo ingresado por el usuario

Comment: @A.Cedano otra consulta que se me ocurre es esta:

SELECT * FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN tiendas_cafe tc ON u.id_usuario=tc.id_tienda WHERE u.correo_usuario OR tc.correo_tienda='usuario@usuario.com' LIMIT 1

Comment: lo que propone jorgnv sería correcto también. Saludos.

Comment: El `OR` o el `AND` es lo de menos. Eso depende del tipo de filtro que quieras aplicar en el contexto de tu aplicación. Mi comentario era una idea de la consulta escrita correctamente.  Es necesario que edites tu pregunta, dando más detalles de la estructura de las tablas, del tipo de filtro que quieres aplicar y cómo se relacionan las tablas. `SELECT * ...` no es una práctica recomendada, ya que debes seleccionar **sólo** aquellas columnas que necesites para esa consulta, no todas las columnas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya acabo de consultar la estructura de las dos tabla, yo lo que quiero saber a cual tabla pertenece el correo ingresado y que me devuelva el resultado de una sola tabla

Comment: La pregunta sigue sin estar clara amigo. ¿Cuántas tablas intervienen, dos o tres? En tu 1ª consulta veo que intervienen tres tablas: `usuarios,  tiendas_cafe y tipos_usuarios`, pero en la pregunta dices que quieres poner en relación dos tablas. Entonces, **¿cuántas tablas intervienen y por qué columnas se relacionan dichas tablas?**. Ejemplo: **_Quiero obtener los datos de la tabla `usuarios` la cual se relaciona con la tabla `tipos_usuarios` a través de la columna `tal_columna`, y con la tabla `tiendas_cafe` mediante la columna... `otra-columna-llave-foranea`_**

Comment: ¿No será lo que quieres un buscador de tiendas y de usuarios al estilo facebook una vez que inicias sesión? ?Donde buscas usuarios, páginas, etc.?

Comment: Si la llave foránea puede estar en una o en otra tabla, necesitas hacer algo parecido a un  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` o bien repensar el diseño de las tablas.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id_usuario, u.id_tipousuario,rol, u.correo_usuario, u.contrasena_usuario, tc.id_tienda,tc.id_tipousuario, tc.correo_tienda, tc.contrasena_tienda
```

//En el from debes poner una tabla (yo dejo usuario) que luego ya relacionarás la otra tabla mediante JOIN:

```
FROM usuarios
```

//Ahora relacionar la otra tabla

```
INNER JOIN tiendas_cafe
```

//Después del inner join debes utilizar un ON con dos columnas que relaciones las tablas. Te he puesto estas pero tú sabrás cuales son concretamente...

```
ON u.id_tipousuario = tc.ts_tipousuario
```

// La condición siguiente debe ser un "=", "like", concatenar, etc o varias condicones, etc, pero hacer un = = = es incorrecto.

WHERE u.correo_usuario = correo_usuario

//Observaciones: si u.correo_usuario = correo_usuario son lo que relacionan una tabla y otr, son junto los que tienes que utilizar para el ON.

Comment: según lo que entiendo de tus recomendaciones sugieres que lo haga de la siguiente manera: 

SELECT * FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN tiendas_cafe tc ON u.id_tipousuario=tc.id_tipousuario WHERE u.correo_usuario OR tc.correo_tienda LIKE '%usuario@usuario.com%'
Pero igual no me funciona

Comment: ¿Estás probando la consulta en el phpmyadmin mismo? O almenos vete poco a poco que ya verás como sale si el planteamiento es correcto. Primero prueba sólo la SELECT * FROM usuario (te devolverá todos los datos de los usuarios). Si funciona, después con el JOIN y el ON (para darte todos los datos de los usuario y de la tienda), si funciona añades el WHERE (se restringira a esa condición que le marcas) con las condiciones poco a poco también. Vete diciendo lo que te funciona y lo que no por favor.

Comment: Si estoy probando la consulta desde el phpmyadmin, colocando esto SELECT * FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN tiendas_cafe tc ON u.id_tipousuario=tc.id_tipousuario no me trae ningun resultado

Comment: ¿Pero paso a paso te da resultado? Haciendo Select * From usuarios...¿Sale algo?

Comment: SELECT id_usuario,id_tipousuario, correo_usuario FROM usuarios
WHERE correo_usuario LIKE '%usuario@usuario.com%'
UNION
SELECT id_tienda,id_tipousuario, correo_tienda FROM tiendas_cafe
WHERE correo_tienda LIKE '%usuario@usuario.com%'

con esta consulta me he acercado a lo que deseo hacer, pero aun no esta correcta